# How to create multiple instance of flask application in same server and same port

Tags: python, flask

How can I run the multiple instance of the flask application in same web-server and same port?

Currently my flask application has following directory structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
├── instance
├── src
    └── __pycache__
```

When application is begun using `flask run`, it runs on default port `localhost:5000`.

I am able to create a copy of the application and run on two ports 5000 & 5001, and it works fine.

However, I wanted to use only one server with an `index.html` file, where
`localhost:5000/index.html` has 2 links for redirection to `localhost:5000/app1/` for app1 and `localhost:5000/app2/` for app2

This is to avoid using of extra port.

I have currently cloned app to app2, however don't know to run two apps.(Below is the directory structure)

```
├── app
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
├── app2
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
├── instance
├── src
    └── __pycache__
```

I have also checked at using Blueprints, but to my understanding they are meant to be used for different views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use werkzeug middleware to do this. It allows you to mount several apps on mount paths like `/app1/` and `/app2/`.

You can read more about it in werkzeug documentation here:
https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.14.x/middlewares/

Comment: Well, I could not solve it yet, but I feel this is the nearest solution. So, working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two apps. You can have index.html include the following lines of code

```py
@app.route('/app1')
def hello():
    return render_template('app1.html')

@app.route('/app2')
def hello():
    return render_template('app2.html')
```

This means you can visit app1 or app2 as specificed (`localhost:5000/app1`) without creating multiple apps

Comment: The idea here is not to have two different HTMLs. But to create two instances of the apps.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa you cannot create multiple instances of an app on the same port

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can ran 2 apps on different ports, and use a reverse proxy to do load balancing on them. [Check out this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing).

As an alternative, you could run multiple instances of your app with something like [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/).

Comment: But we cannot run multiple instances of the apps in single port using gunicorn.